# Why are my imported Google Fonts not working in my Expo React Native app?

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, expo, google-fonts

I have followed the official *expo/google-fonts* README, and yet I can't seem to get my fonts working in my app. I started by running the following command to install the necessary packages:

```
expo install @expo-google-fonts/inter expo-font expo-app-loading
```

Here's what my **App.tsx** file looks like:

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Navigation from "./navigation";
import Onboarding from "./screens/onboarding";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store, { persistor } from "./store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import useFirstTimeCheck from "./hooks/useFirstTimeCheck";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import {
  useFonts,
  Inter_100Thin,
  Inter_200ExtraLight,
  Inter_300Light,
  Inter_400Regular,
  Inter_500Medium,
  Inter_600SemiBold,
  Inter_700Bold,
  Inter_800ExtraBold,
  Inter_900Black,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/inter";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Inter_100Thin,
    Inter_200ExtraLight,
    Inter_300Light,
    Inter_400Regular,
    Inter_500Medium,
    Inter_600SemiBold,
    Inter_700Bold,
    Inter_800ExtraBold,
    Inter_900Black,
  });
  const { firstTime, setNotFirstTime } = useFirstTimeCheck();

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
            {firstTime ? (
              <Onboarding handleOnboarding={setNotFirstTime} />
            ) : (
              <Navigation />
            )}
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, I do import the fonts and load them (I know AppLoading is technically depreciated, I just want to fix my fonts before I work on switching to SplashScreen). Now, when I go to **another .TSX file** in my code and add the following style to a Text element:

```
  title: {
    fontSize: 34,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    flex: 3,
    fontFamily: "Inter_700Bold",
  },
```

It just doesn't change. I refresh the app on the emulator, but nothing. Am I supposed to import something in order for my fonts to work in other files?